# Shared Libraries Not Found

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, software-distribution

I have a program that uses a number of shared libraries. I can compile and run the program fine on the machine used to compile the program. When I try to copy the executable to another machine and run it after installing the required packages via apt-get, I get the following error:

> "error while loading shared libraries: libconfig++.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

After running `$ locate libconfig++.so`, I learn that I have libconfig++.so.9  installed on my current system as opposed to libconfig.so.8.

I then manually copied all of the shared libraries to the new system along with the executable, the program then ran fine. I do not think that this would be a long term solution since the libraries would not receive patches and updates that they normally would, thus creating a potential security risk.

Is there any way that I can compile my program so that it is dependent on libconfig++.so as opposed to libconfig++.so.x or is there some way for me to manually include specific shared libraries while still enabling them to be updated?

I have also considered the fact that I am doing something completely wrong in the manner that I am distributing my program. Is there a way to distribute my program in a manner such that this is avoided altogether?

Comment: Most Linux programs use source redistribution, they are compiled as part of installation process. What you want to have is "linux binary redistribution" - just type this in Google and enjoy reading - this is complicated problem.

Comment: @Sathish: No _don't_ do that. The versioning scheme exists for a reason and bypassing it is just stupid, since you _know_ the version changed because the ABI changed.

Comment: @Zachary: Build _on_ the target machine, or one just like it.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile your program with -lsomelibrary, the compiler will search for libsomelibrary.so in your system, which will be linked to something like libsomelibrary.so.x.y From now on, your software is tied to that particular **major** version (that x in the name).

This means that it will only work with the x series library. If the distribution ships a newer version with the same major version (say libsomelibrary.x.z), your application should work correctly.

However, you're **not** allowed to use another major version of the library. If you do (by linking a major version to a different version), as somebody suggested here, the application may start (or may crash right at the start), but you'll never be sure that the application will work as planned.

**TL'DR:**

When you compile, the linker looks for libsomelibrary.so, which will be linked to a specific version like libsomelibrary.so.x.y.

When you run your application, the system will look for libsomelibrary.so.x.* (same major version, any minor version)

For more in depth info on that matter, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-shlibs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your last paragraph: The standard way for distributing binaries (specially ones that depend on shared objects), is using your target distribution's package management system (dpkg, rpm, or both). These package formats will require the system to have the dependencies installed (libconfig++, in your case). And if not, the user can use apt/yum to automatically download and install them.

Comment: This doesn't help if you have a binary compiled on a different system and it needs package versions which are not in the target system's repo

Comment: Yes @JonathanWakely, I was actually mentioning the standard distribution mechanism for binaries. I added this to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

verify your makefile if its asking for version 9 shared lib to be loaded.

Its depends on the usage of a function which your program invokes.

Say if there is no major change w.r.t function you invoking between 8 - 9th version of library , you dont need to potentially copy the lib's.

Of course creating symbolic like would like.

If you think, your program shouldn't have dependency with all these stuffs.

Go for static library, you would able to find libconfig.a archive, you can link with your program , hence no dependency when you run other machines.